# parse a string multiple delimiters returning list of tuples with style and text

Tags: python, markdown, pyparsing, ply

I'm trying to parse a string which will have some markdown style delimiters in it. I need a list back with the styles. I've given it a go with pyparsing and have had some success, but feel there is probably a better method (basically using the post by mbeaches at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Essentially, if I have a string

```
word_paragraph = "This is **bold** and this is *italic* sample"
```

I'd like to return a list of tuples after providing:

```
style_delim = {'Bold': '**', 'Italics':'*', } 
word_pg_parsed = somefunction(word_paragraph,style_delim)
```

which would result in word_pg_parsed as something like:

```
word_pg_parsed = [('Normal','This is '),('Bold','bold'),('Normal','and this is '),('Italics','italic'),('Normal',' sample')]
```

I've looked into markdown, but can't find where this functionality exists. I suspect there is a library (dug into PLY but couldn't find what I am after) that handles this properly.

Why? I'm attempting to create a word file using python-docx file including some text from some marked up text and need to handle the inline character styles accordingly. Is there something in python-markdown or other library anyone has seen that does this?

Comment: The reference Markdown implementation (Perl) uses regex string substitutions to modify the source document in place. Python-Markdown uses regex to build an ElementTree object. No list of tokens is ever generated in either case. That said, some Markdown implementations may do so (Mistune is the only Python lib I'm aware of). However, if you want to use pyparsing, you might want to look at some of the Markdown implementations which use PEG parsers  for inspiration (none of which are implemented in Python AFAIK). A search for PEGMarkdown should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Here is a two year old blog post about [Python Markdown parsers](http://lepture.com/en/2014/markdown-parsers-in-python).

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of Markdown implementations, each of which parses Markdown slightly differently. Here is an incomplete list: https://github.com/markdown/markdown.github.com/wiki/Implementations

Comment: The article @StevenRumbalski linked to is authored by the developer of Mistune. Haven't used the lib myself so I can't recommend it, but its list of tokens might just serve your needs. Full disclosure: I'm the developer of the Python-Markdown lib.

Comment: thank you @Waylan, amazing to get the confirmation from the developer of python-markdown. I'll dig into mistune, had not heard of it.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event someone is looking to do this, here's what I found. Many thanks to Waylan for pointing me to mistune and to lepture for the library.

The default_output method was replaced with placeholder. That's the one you need to override to get the list instead of a string. Referenced here: https://github.com/lepture/mistune/pull/20

Basically follow what is in the test case at:
https://github.com/lepture/mistune/blob/878f92bdb224a8b7830e8c33952bd2f368e5d711/tests/test_subclassing.py The **getattribute** is indeed required, otherwise you'll errors about string functions being called on a list.

Look for TokenTreeRenderer in the test_subclassing.py.

Repeating here in a django views.py for my working sample:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ParseForm   # simple form with textarea field called markup
import mistune


class TokenTreeRenderer(mistune.Renderer):
    # options is required
    options = {}

    def placeholder(self):
        return []

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        """Saves the arguments to each Markdown handling method."""
        found = TokenTreeRenderer.__dict__.get(name)
        if found is not None:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

        def fake_method(*args, **kwargs):
            return [(name, args, kwargs)]
        return fake_method


def parse(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parse_form = ParseForm(request.POST)
        if parse_form.is_valid():
            # parse the data
            markdown = mistune.Markdown(renderer=TokenTreeRenderer())
            tokenized = markdown(parse_form.cleaned_data['markup'])
            context.update({'tokenized': tokenized, })
            # no need for a redirect in this case

    else:
        parse_form = ParseForm(initial={'markup': 'This is a **bold** text sample', })

    context.update({'form': parse_form, })
    return render(request, 'mctests/parse.html', context)
```

This results in output of:

```
 [('paragraph', ([('text', (u'This is a ',), {}), ('double_emphasis', ([('text', (u'bold',), {})],), {}), ('text', (u' text sample',), {})],), {})]
```

which works great for me.